# string variable of cwd

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7, python-os

Input

```
import os
my_cwd = str(os.system("cd"))
```

Output

> > C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2

Input

```
my_cwd
```

Output

> > '0'

I would expect calling my_cwd would return `'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2'` what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.system` returns the *return code* of the command *as an integer* (that's why you tried to convert to `str`), not the output of the command as a string.

To get the output, you could use `subprocess.check_output` (`subprocess.run` in python 3.5+) with `shell=True` since `cd` is built-in:

```
import subprocess
value = subprocess.check_output(["cd"],shell=True)
```

(`check_output` raises an exception if the command fails, though)

You also have to "cleanup" the output by using `value.rstrip()` and decode the result into a string, since `subprocess.check_output` returns a `bytes` object... Also, your code is not portable on Linux, since the required command would be `pwd`.

Well, that very complex to just get the current directory (leave that kind of stuff for `cls` or `clear` commands). The most pythonic way to get it is to use:

```
os.getcwd()
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you, Jean.  I'll accept in 12 mins after the cooldown.

Comment: `cd` emits output on stdout? I wouldn't expect the first form to work at all. (Perhaps the call should be to `pwd`?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, just checked.

Comment: Ahh, *Windows*. (On UNIX-y platforms, that first command's output *will* come back empty).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy using windows 7 professional.  'pwd' throws "pwd is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: @py_noob, right -- I don't do Windows; the comment above was pertinent to other platforms.

Comment: that's `pwd` on Linux. `cd` prints current path on Windows

Comment: Yup. Question didn't specify a platform, except inasmuch as what one could infer from the ```C:\ ``` paths.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy anyway: edited the answer. Definitely not a good idea to use a system call to get current directory.

Comment: (I had to look that up) @CharlesDuffy `cd` just changes current dir to home directory on Linux/Unix. Too much Windows lately (well, those last 10 years actually!)